# Automating recompilation in emacs/slime live environment

Tags: emacs, macros, common-lisp, slime

Given this situation:

```
(defmacro mac1 ...)

(defun func1 () 
  (mac1 ...))
```

Redefinition of `mac1` in the live environment will not affect `func1` until it is itself recompiled.

Is there a way to get emacs or lisp to automatically recompile `func1` whenever `mac1` is recompiled?

Something like this in the source would be acceptable:

```
(watch
  (defmacro mac1 ...))

(on-signal (mac1)
  (defun func1 ...))
```

Not that hard to implement, but I would rather avoid wheel reinvention.

Comment: Not a real answer, but if you're willing to break into the `cl` package, you can stash the function's source as a property of its symbol name in a wrapper around `defun`, and have a second wrapper around `defmacro` to look at `who-macroexpands` and iterate over those stashed sources. Or just `slime-compile-and-load-file` when you lose track of what your macro edits might have done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macros are not necessarily compiled. If you are using SBCL (see [manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Interpreter)), there is a variable named `sb-ext:*evaluator-mode*` which can be set to `:interpret` so that macro are expanded during evaluation. Other implementations might provide something similar. That allows you to change the definitions of macros without recompiling call sites like you already do with functions.

Alternatively, slime defines a function named `slime-who-macroexpands`. You'd have to dig a little bit to see how it works and maybe exploit it, either in the Common Lisp environment (swank) or the emacs side.

Answer (score 1):

For example in LispWorks you can do the following. Probably SBCL has a similar facility.

Let's say we have this:

```
(defmacro foo ()
  `(list 1 2 3))

(defun bar () (first (foo)))
(defun baz () (second (foo)))
```

Now you can ask who calls `foo`:

```
CL-USER 11 > (who-calls 'foo)
(BAZ BAR)
```

This makes it easy to re-compile both functions:

```
CL-USER 12 > (mapcar 'compile (who-calls 'foo))
;;;*** Warning in BAZ: The definition of BAZ is already compiled.
;;;*** Warning in BAR: The definition of BAR is already compiled.
(BAZ BAR)
```

Since LispWorks keeps a who-calls database, one can recompile all functions which directly use and depend on other functions/macros.

The editor has the command `Edit Callers` and `Continue Tags Search` to find the callers and then to recompile them manually. It should be easy/possible to write an editor command which recompiles all callers.

Comment: The last example is a bit misleading, recompiling already compiled functions has no effect on most implementations, definitely on all current implementations that compile to native machine code.  Please add a remark on or before the example.

Comment: NB. The SBCL analogue is `sb-introspect:who-macroexpands` … and the Slime function is `slime-who-macroexpands`. However, `sb-introspect:who-macroexpands` returns an alist of symbols and `definition-source` structures, and passing the symbol to `compile` has no effect; you'd have to maybe use the `definition-source-pathname` or something to trace it.